# Java Virtual Machine Launcher error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-10

I try to play Minecraft. When I try to play an error shows:

> Java Virtual Machine Launcher
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I tried to update to Java 8, uninstall and reinstall, set my 'JAVA_HOME' to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_221`, set my '_JAVA_OPTIONS' to `-Xmx512M`, but the error is still there.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Shiginima](https://teamshiginima.com/) is a custom minecraft launcher, making this question off-topic as tech sipport for modded Minecraft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted Java SE, Java RE and all Java components from my computer and only reinstall the JRE. Now I can launch Minecraft.